# C++ real time snake like game console without multithreading

Tags: c++, input, console, cin

I want to make snake game in console using c++, but I don't want to wait every "frame" for user input.
If i'll use cin or getch (), program will wait for player input every frame:

```
while (game)
{
    c = getch (); //input
    snake.move (c); //moving
    draw (); //drawing
}
```

How to move snake and draw it in console and don't waiting for input every frame?

Is there any way to do that without multithreating?
Maybe something like put something in cin buffer in code instead of using console? Is it doable?

Comment: look into SFML read the tutorials especially the graphics and events.

Comment: I don't want using SFML. I want just standard C++

Comment: There is no standard non blocking read AFIAK.  This is why you would use two threads.

Comment: Is there built-in threat support in c++? C++ in code::blocks don't fully support c++ 11, so new threads are unavaible.

Comment: The C++ standard library provides an intersection of the set of tools required by a variety of tasks, rather than their union. Bjarne Stroustrup mentions in his "The C++ programming language 4th edition" that it is likely only suitable and sufficient for very low level embedded development and systems programming/OS development. If you want to make a minimalistic game just for grins and giggles good luck. keep in mind openGL is NOT a part of standard C++, no matter how low level

Comment: Is there any way to put something in cin buffer by script?

Comment: There would be a platform-dependent way of doing this, e.g. on Windows you can use `GetAsyncKeyState()`.

Comment: Sometimes there is a problem, when I want do something like:
int number;
cin >> number;
and I put a letter in to the number variable. Because cin can't put letter in to the int so that letter stay in buffer forever (until I use cin.clear (); cin.sync ();). Is there any way to put something in cin? Simulating console input? Like cin.putIn("letters");?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use standard C++ because there is no guarantee that when the User presses a key, the key press will be acknowledged immediately.  Many implementations wait for the Enter key to be pressed, then process the input buffer.

You will need an *event driven system*.  You want the OS or hardware to notify your program that a key press event has occurred.  In this kind of system, you would move the snake during the event handler.

Another method is to *poll* the switch status.  When the key is released, you could move the snake.

All of the above solutions require platform or OS specific functionality.

Comment: conio.h getch () works without enter needed I'm using windows so it's enough. I just want add something to the buffer by code instead of console.

Comment: The `conio.h` file is not part of standard C++.

Comment: It is part of windows c++, but it is attached to every good compiler.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have several good compilers like IAR, Greenhills, Mingw, GNU.  These don't have `conio.h` attached.  So, I guess they are not good compilers.

Comment: Are you using linuks?

Comment: I'm using multiple platforms, many of which are embedded systems.  I haven't used a *linuks* distribution, although I have a Linux distribution at home.  I have written Windows console and windowing applications.